# Evaluating a double integral with absolute values using Tonelli's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals, multiple-integral

I'm trying to solve the following integral:
$$\iint_{R} \left| \frac{y \cos{y}}{\sqrt{x}} \right| dA$$
where R is the rectangle $[0,1] \times [0,3]$.

Using Tonelli's theorem, I can say the following:
$$\iint_{R} \left| \frac{y \cos{y}}{\sqrt{x}} \right| dA = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{3} \left| \frac{y \cos{y}}{\sqrt{x}} \right| dy dx \int_{0}^{3} \int_{0}^{1} \left| \frac{y \cos{y}}{\sqrt{x}} \right| dx dy  $$

I've tried to split the region into positive and negative parts, since when $y$ is less than $\frac{\pi}{2}$, cosine is positive, whereas when it is greater than $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and less than 3, it is negative.

However, I don't know how exactly to deal with the unboundedness of the function on the line $x=0$ (and the points when $y=0$ and $y=\frac{\pi}{2}$ on this line). I know that Fubini's/Tonelli's theorems work for improper integrals too, where the function becomes unbounded) as long as the condition are met (i.e. Lebsgue integrability for Fubini and non-negativity for Tonelli), but that is when one point blows up to infinity, whereas this is a whole line, so I don't really know what difference that would make).

Any help on breaking down this absolute value integral would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tonelli's Theorem states that if $X$ and $Y$ are $\sigma$-finite measure spaces and $f:X\times Y\to[0,\infty]$ is measurable then $\int_X\int_Yf=\int_Y\int_Xf=\int_{X\times Y}f$ (even if those integrals are infinite).  Clearly, $[0,1]$ and $[0,3]$ are $\sigma$-finite, and your $f$ is nonnegative by definition.  The fact that $f=\infty$ on a line segment makes no difference.

So $\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx=2$.  Integration by parts gives us $\int y\cos(y)\,dy=\cos(y) + y\sin(y)$, and then you break up the definite integral as needed to account for the absolute value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the instance that I had a similar absolute value integral, except one of the variables went from 0 to infinity, then how would that affect the sigma-finiteness of the measure space?

Comment: Every measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is $\sigma$-finite, so Tonelli's Theorem always applies in this setting.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your help. So would I be right in saying that any "normal integration" without anything too abstract would have X and Y being sigma-finite? So Fubini/Tonelli can be assumed to always apply for these cases?

Answer (score 1):

You can write the last iterated integral as
$$ \int_0^3 y |\!\cos y| \, dy \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt x} \, dx$$
so you only have to deal with two one-dimensional integrals. The first equals
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} y \cos y \, dy - \int_{\pi/2}^3 y \cos y \, dy$$ and the second integral evaluates to $2$.

Comment: Oh yes because it's a product! Hypothetically, how would you proceed if it wasn't a product, and you had discontinuity like that? So for example, if I had square-root of xy in the denominator instead of x alone?

Comment: For instance $\int_0^1\int_0^1|x-y|\,dx\,dy=\int_0^1\int_0^yy-x\,dx\,dy+\int_0^1\int_y^1x-y\,dx\,dy$.